# Adding html tag in between post body

Tags: laravel

hello guys I  want too add html tag and also adsense ads in between the post body {{ $post->body }} please how can i do this

something like this

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas vitae scel<span id="dots">...</span><span id="more">erisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum

adsense code displays here

 dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta.</span>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, this is not a website to solve any problems for you, it is rather a site where you can come for hints or show your code that you already tried, but don't expect a full solution from here, try something yourself and then ask why it doesn't work or how it can be improved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace `{{ $post->body }}` with `{!! $post->body !!}`  .